# how does __glibcxx_function_requires and __glibcxx_requires_valid_range macros work?

Tags: c++, stl, macros, accumulate

```
template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Tp, typename _BinaryOperation>
inline _Tp
accumulate(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Tp __init, _BinaryOperation __binary_op)
{
    // concept requirements
    __glibcxx_function_requires(_InputIteratorConcept<_InputIterator>)
    __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first, __last);

    for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
        __init = __binary_op(__init, *__first);
    return __init;
}
```

I looked at definition of accumulate function in stl library.
Here I found two macros __glibcxx_function_requires and __glibcxx_requires_valid_range, which are defined like this:

```
#define __glibcxx_function_requires(...)
# define __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(_First,_Last)
```

Please can you explain me, how they work and what they are doing ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When `_GLIBCXX_CONCEPT_CHECKS` is defined, so is this.

```
#define __glibcxx_function_requires(...)                                 \
         __gnu_cxx::__function_requires< __gnu_cxx::__VA_ARGS__ >();
```

So your posted code:

```
__glibcxx_function_requires(_InputIteratorConcept<_InputIterator>)
```

Resolves to this:

```
__gnu_cxx::__function_requires< _InputIteratorConcept<_InputIterator> >();
```

Which inlines to:

```
void (_InputIteratorConcept<_InputIterator>::*__x)() _IsUnused = &_InputIteratorConcept<_InputIterator>::__constraints;
```

This forces an instantiation of `_InputIteratorConcept<_InputIterator>::__constraints`, which uses `typedef`s to break compilation when `_InputIterator` doesn't resemble an iterator.

`__glibcxx_requires_valid_range` uses a similar technique to call [one of several](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/libstdc++/api/a00890_source.html#l00140) functions, depending on the iterator type.  When appropriate (and fast enough), it will assert that `__last` comes after `__first`